# JS Infinite loop : FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory, infinite-loop

Getting a memory heap error while executing an infinite loop

```
function test() {
        let pairContract;
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            let pairContract = new web3.eth.Contract(UNISWAP_ABI, '0x2e81ec0b8b4022fac83a21b2f2b4b8f5ed744d70');
            pairContract = null;
        }
 }

const init = () => {
    do {
        test();
    } while (1);
};

init();
```

Basically new web3.eth.Contract generates a complex object.

The problem seems to be that each instance of pairContract is never fully deleted from memory after a previous test() execution.

I tried to replace the do while with a setInterval but it didn't work. Also tried a recursive approach with a process.nextTick at the end of the test function but it didn't work either.

Increasing --max-old-space-size ends up with the same error code as stated in the title.

Node version : v12.20.0

Comment: A `setInterval` or recursive asynchronous approach looks reasonable, what problems were you encountering with it?

Comment: I got the same error: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Comment: Sounds like you aren't giving it enough time to garbage collect

Comment: @CertainPerformance I wasn't aware that I should give time to garbage collect. I'm pretty nooby about memory management. Are you suggesting I should add some timer somewhere?

Comment: Try giving it more time. Increase the timeout to 10s or 30s or so and see if you can tell a difference.

Comment: Problem is my real use case needs to be the fastest possible between 2 executions of test function. Putting a timer of few ms would be ok but few seconds is too much

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It appeared that using a web3 instance with global scope to create the pairContract prevented it to be garbage collected.

Creating the web3 instance with `const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545')` within the test function solved the problem.